# Ceylon modules in different versions?

Tags: ceylon

I'm trying to make a simple app that utilizes the `ceylon.http.server`, `ceylon.json`, `ceylon.io` modules.

When I compile, I get these errors:

```
Error:(4, 8) ceylon: source code imports two different versions of module 'com.redhat.ceylon.langtools.classfile': version '1.3.1' and version '1.3.2'
Error:(4, 8) ceylon: source code imports two different versions of module 'com.redhat.ceylon.model': version '1.3.1' and version '1.3.2'
Error:(4, 8) ceylon: source code imports two different versions of module 'com.redhat.ceylon.common': version '1.3.1' and version '1.3.2'
```

Why do I get them? I thought Ceylon could handle utilizing the same module in different versions. In the [Ceylon tour, Packages and modules](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/tour/modules/) it explicitly says "A runtime that features module isolation and the ability to manage multiple versions of the same module".

My `module.ceylon` looks like this:

```
native ("jvm")
module server "1.0.0" {
    import ceylon.http.server "1.3.2";
    import ceylon.json "1.3.2";
    import ceylon.io "1.3.2";
}
```

My (only) source file `runServer.ceylon` looks like this:

```
import ceylon.http.server { ... }
import ceylon.io { ... }

"Run the module `server`."
shared void runServer() {

    //create a HTTP server
    value server = newServer {
        //an endpoint, on the path /hello
            Endpoint {
                path = startsWith("/hello");
                //handle requests to this path
                service(Request request, Response response) =>
                        response.writeString("hello world");
            }
    };

    //start the server on port 8080
    server.start(SocketAddress("127.0.0.1",8080));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example code works for me. Is it possible that you are trying to compile this with Ceylon 1.3.1? I think the three modules in the error message are all dependencies of the language module, so I suspect that `ceylon.http.server` and the other imported modules pull in `ceylon.language/1.3.2` and your compiler adds `ceylon.language/1.3.1`.